# KnockoutJS - Nested Data, Loading Children

Tags: knockout.js

I am very very new to knockoutjs - having worked through the tutorials 
and I have made a nice start. I have application which seems well suited 
to KO. In that I need to populate a table with data from JSON. This 
data is nested, and can be nested at any depth, but my API will only 
ever return data two levels deep.

E.g.

- Node 1
- - Node A
- - Node B

I've managed to get the data to load into my table, lovely. I've taken 
this a step further and have supported nesting. I have a requirement so that if a Node has children, it can be injected beneath the Node into the table.

An example of this would be...

- Node 1 (HasChildren)
- - Node A
- - Node B (HasChildren)

As Node B 'HasChildren', I would like to allow the loading of it's children into the table, beneath Node B. In this event, I would be able to query my API, and it would return the children for Node B

- Node 1
- - Node A
- - Node B
- - - Node B1
- - - Node B2

> I've got something roughly working, but it only works on a level 1 
>   node. Once it get's to level2, can't seem to find my method 
>   (addChild). I can't work out why it cannot find the method, as it is
>   in my  ViewModel.
>
> The post below, goes a long way to fixing this part of the problem.

Help!

I've pasted the code here... (if you scroll to the right on the table, 
you can click open, to see, what's happening!)

http://jsfiddle.net/8k6pj/1/ - Original Version (18th April 2012)

**[http://jsfiddle.net/8k6pj/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/8k6pj/3/) - Latest Version**

Many thanks in advance!

Laurence

p.s Have further updated my code, so although I'm a bit stuck on the above, have started looking into implementing how the code will postback so we can save.

It looks like the postback is working, however it does not post back the changed values, the original values are posted back. Think this is because I need to use an ObservableArray, exploring that now.

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know I gave this a good shot. My feeling right now is the view binding logic is a bit convoluted. I'm debating refactoring it to see if I can uncover the issue. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Have updated the code/question, so hopefully it makes a bit more sense (: Lau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a go at understanding what you would like to happen, I'm still a bit unclear but thought I'd submit what I did in order to provoke more info if needed.

Your question title mentions nesting but from your code it appears you aren't nesting anything, instead you are flattening your nested parent child objects.

Instead of using jquery delegates which I would not recommend since it breaks encapsulation of your models, I changed your template to use click bindings and placed an open function on the Crew/Component objects.

```
<td rowspan="3">
    <a data-bind="click: open">Open</a>
    <a>Save</a>
</td>
```

I also noticed that your addChild method requires you to pass an array to it. Your original code would not have worked as the Crew objects don't themselves have a Crews collection so i took a guess an used the Crews collection on their parent Component.

All these alterations meant I had to pass through the root viewModels and the parent components on the constructors.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/fdb5r/2/

FYI - This fiddle still throws errors when clicking Open as the Allocated objects don't get initialized correctly. I've left this upto you to fix since I don't understand the domain enough to fix it myself. The adding behavior works correctly though.

**EDIT after updated question**

Here's a re factored and simplified example that should get you started. I removed a lot of the non-essential stuff to make it clearer how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/xxGam/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Madcapnmckay - Thanks for your help! That already makes a bit more sense. Your right I'm going wrong with the nesting. I've updated the question above to try and clarify things a bit! Thanks again for your time, Lau

Comment: @uniquelau - Hey. Thanks for clarifying. I'll try and produce a simplified example. One question. What is the difference between Crew and Component from the UI perspective? Could they be unified into one object?

Comment: No difference at all! It's the same object, I only called it a different name, as I could not make it reuse the same object.

Comment: Thank you again for your time on this. The above is really helpful. Just working through this at the moment, working out how each part works and then integrating the remaining functionality. Will post back the final solution here too.

Comment: Thank you again for your help on this one.

Comment: Hello. I've got one extra question. I've been struggling with this one too. In my original example, I had a row called Allocation. I've updated this row, to allow data input, which can then be posted to my API (this all works nicely).

However I would like to have a live total for Allocation. I know I need to add this code into the 'var Component', but I can't figure out how to examine the Allocation object, and total up it's values.

Comment: @uniquelau - Would you mind posting as a separate question. I'll take a look.

Comment: Here we go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285588/knockoutjs-row-and-column-calculations (: Lau

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at ko.mapping to handle some of the data loading you are working on. I think it will help out with some of the data issues you are having

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you, looking through this now.